# What happens when a non-root user sends signals to root user's process?

Tags: security, signals

I'm wondering about the security of UNIX signals.

`SIGKILL` will kill the process. So, what happens when a non root user's process sends a signal to a root user's process? Does the process still carry out the signal handler?

I follow the accepted answer (gollum's), and I type `man capabilites`, and I find a lot of things about the Linux kernel. From [`man capabilities`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

```
NAME

   capabilities - overview of Linux capabilities
DESCRIPTION

   For the purpose of performing permission checks, traditional UNIX
   implementations distinguish two categories of processes: privileged
   processes (whose effective user ID is 0, referred to as superuser or
   root), and unprivileged processes (whose effective UID is nonzero).
   Privileged processes bypass all kernel permission checks, while
   unprivileged processes are subject to full permission checking based
   on the process's credentials (usually: effective UID, effective GID,
   and supplementary group list).

   Starting with kernel 2.2, Linux divides the privileges traditionally
   associated with superuser into distinct units, known as capabilities,
   which can be independently enabled and disabled.  Capabilities are a
   per-thread attribute.
```

Comment: Other than `SIGKILL`, which is a special case and managed completely by the kernel, signals are merely a request. The receiving process can do anything they want with them.

Comment: @chepner Other than `SIGKILL` **and** `SIGSTOP`...

Comment: @chepner The receiving process has to actively decide it wants to handle the signal. If the receiving process hasn't done so, then a lot of signals will by default kill the process in exactly the same way `SIGKILL` would. Initially `SIGINT`, `SIGKILL`, and `SIGTERM` will have the exact same effect, the only difference is that the receiving process can change this default for some of them.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On Linux it depends on the file capabilities.

Take the following simple `mykill.c` source:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void exit_usage(const char *prog) {
        printf("usage: %s -<signal> <pid>\n", prog);
        exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        pid_t pid;
        int sig;

        if (argc != 3)
                exit_usage(argv[0]);

        sig = atoi(argv[1]);
        pid = atoi(argv[2]);

        if (sig >= 0 || pid < 2)
                exit_usage(argv[0]);

        if (kill(pid, -sig) == -1) {
                perror("failed");
                return 1;
        }
        printf("successfully sent signal %d to process %d\n", -sig, pid);

        return 0;
}
```

build it:

```
gcc -Wall mykill.c -o /tmp/mykill
```

Now as user root start a sleep process in background:

```
root@horny:/root# /bin/sleep 3600 &
[1] 16098
```

Now as normal user try to kill it:

```
demouser@horny:/home/demouser$ ps aux | grep sleep
root     16098  0.0  0.0  11652   696 pts/20   S    15:06   0:00 sleep 500

demouser@horny:/home/demouser$ /tmp/mykill -9 16098
failed: Operation not permitted
```

Now as root user change the `/tmp/mykill` caps:

```
root@horny:/root# setcap cap_kill+ep /tmp/mykill
```

And try again as normal user:

```
demouser@horny:/home/demouser$ /tmp/mykill -9 16098
successfully sent signal 9 to process 16098
```

Finally please delete `/tmp/mykill` for obvious reasons ;)

Comment: Follow your clue, I type "man capabilities" and I find a lot of thing about linux kernel

Comment: Are we not gonna talk about the machine name here??

Answer (score 25):

Nothing:

```
strace kill -HUP 1
[...]
kill(1, SIGHUP)    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
[...]
```

Comment: Is this kind of security done by os level or hard coded in user's signal handler ?

Comment: @lovespring The kernel doesn't deliver the signal to the target process. The syscall is returned with an error and apart from that ignored.

Comment: That is not true in general. It depends on the capabilities.

Comment: @lovespring: Yeah it's the kernel that makes these checks. Userspace processes simply don't have enough control over that.

Comment: @gollum: NB The question is about Unix in general - capabilities are a Linux-specific (and nonstandard) feature.

Comment: @psmears  yes, but others have similar concepts (e.g. "privileges" on solaris). So the answer "Nothing" is definitely wrong.

Comment: @gollum: It's not exactly *wrong* (after all, it is the default behaviour on all Unix-family OSs, and the only one possible on many - including older Linux kernels for instance) but you're right that it's incomplete - but just mentioning "capabilities" without going into more detail about where they are suported is also incomplete in a question about general Unix :)

Comment: @psmears agreed

Answer (score 5):

`kill(2)` man page explains:

> Linux Notes
>
> Across  different  kernel  versions,  Linux has enforced different rules for the permissions required for an unprivileged
>   process to
>          send a signal to another process.  In kernels 1.0 to 1.2.2, a signal could be sent if the effective user ID of  the  sender  matched
>          that  of  the  receiver,  or  the real user ID of the sender matched that of the receiver.  From kernel 1.2.3 until 1.3.77, a
>   signal
>          could be sent if the effective user ID of the sender matched either the real or effective user ID  of  the  receiver.   The 
>   current
>          rules, which conform to POSIX.1-2001, were adopted in kernel 1.3.78.

Comment: 1.3.78 is extremely ancient history, as 1.3. dates from 1995 or thereabouts. 1.3 was the development series leading up to 2.0 (in 1996)

Comment: @vonbrand Probably the cited man pages need some update.

Answer (score -1):

the signal would carry but the process owner belong to root. so, the other user don't have the right to terminate the process so you will receive permission error problem.

terminate process is only possible when you own the ownership(proper rights) of the process.

Comment: No, sys_kill gives back -1 and errno will be -EPERM.